# Is there any working memory profiler for Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, profiling, memory-profiling, memory-leak-detector

In Python 2 there's a couple of tools but everything seems to be old and out-of-dated.

I've found PySizer and Heapy but everything seems to be Python2 oriented and would take a lot of effort to port.

objgraph is interesting but still not a fully working profiler

Which tool are using ?

Comment: btw, the `sys.getsizeof` function mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416654/is-there-a-memory-profiler-for-python2-7 works for Python 3.2 as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I profile memory usage in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552744/how-do-i-profile-memory-usage-in-python)

Comment: YiFei Zhu has ported Guppy-PE/Heapy to Python 3 creating Guppy3. It can be reached here:
https://github.com/zhuyifei1999/guppy3/

Answer (score 12):

[Pympler](http://packages.python.org/Pympler/) is a Python memory profiler that is compatible with both Python 2.x and Python3.x.

Answer (score 4):

[objgraph](http://mg.pov.lt/objgraph/) is compatible with Python 3

Answer (score 2):

`memprof` works for Python3:

http://jmdana.github.io/memprof/

It will log and plot the memory footprint of all your variables.