# Profiling memory in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any working memory profiler for Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758699/is-there-any-working-memory-profiler-for-python3)

I'd like to know how much memory used for my objects. I used guppy for this before, but now I work with python 3, but guppy works under python 2. What can I use for memory profiling in python 3? (I makes standalone application not web-based)

Answer (score 8):

[objgraph](http://mg.pov.lt/objgraph/) works in Python 3

Comment: I found [pympler](http://packages.python.org/Pympler/) for getting size of objects. With objgraph it can be use like this - pympler.asizeof.asizeof(objgraph.by_type('set'))