# Is there an online memory profiler for python2.7?

Tags: python

[Which Python memory profiler is recommended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259/python-memory-profiler)

[Is there any working memory profiler for Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758699/is-there-any-working-memory-profiler-for-python3)
I've checked these posts

But I'm interested to know is there any online tool where you can post your code and get the job done?

Comment: @shx2 while solving problems on codechef i cross the limit of memory usage,so just want to check and optimise the code

Comment: Perhaps a better question would be: "Excessive Memory Usage when Reading a File" along with your source code.