# Typical Application and Use Cases for Python Decorators

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

While recently reading this [article](http://www.thumbtack.com/engineering/a-primer-on-python-decorators/) on Python decorators, it gave as example the technique of [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) as an application of Python decorators. While I have a working understanding of Python decorators I wish to know of more such effective use cases for decorators, and how do you typically use them in your everyday code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is memoization good for and is it really all that helpful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242597/what-is-memoization-good-for-and-is-it-really-all-that-helpful)

Comment: I realise that duplicate is not Python-specific, but I think it answers your question.

Comment: @detly Actually no, My question isn't at all about memoization, I merely wanted to illustrate with an example. My question is specifically about python Decorators and their Good use cases like memoization

Comment: Ah, you're right. But I can't withdraw the close vote dammit.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of built-in decorators that can be useful, such as `classmethod`, `property`, `staticmethod`, and `functools.wrap`.  It is often handy to write a decorator that logs usage of functions for debugging purposes.  There are lots of example decorators on [this Python wiki page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary), though I think at least some of these are more aimed at showing off how flexible Python is than actually providing useful functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Since Python 3 supports type annotations, decorators can be used as a way to check.

```
def check(f):
    def _f(x):
        if type(x) != f.__annotations__['x']:
            raise TypeError(type(x))
        val = f(x)
        if 'return' in f.__annotations__ and f.__annotations__['return'] != type(val):
            raise TypeError(type(val))
        return val
    return _f

@check
def f(x: int) -> int:
    return x * 2

>>> f(2)
4

>>> f('x')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in _f
TypeError: <class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at effective use cases for python decorators in the Django web framework `auth` [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/). Clear examples (I personally use on an everyday basis) include the usage of decorators for [restricting views to authenticated users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator), [restricting access depending on specific user permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#the-permission-required-decorator), etc.

Comment: For ease of others @Josvic answer might be referring to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/) among others.

Comment: @subiet Exactly. I just referred to specific ones I really find useful :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a practical example. Take a look at fibonacci's series sum with and without memo.

```
from functools import wraps
def memo(func): 
    cache = {}
    @wraps(func)
    def wrap(*args):
        if args not in cache: 
            cache[args] = func(*args)
        return cache[args] 
    return wrap

def fib(i):
    if i < 2: return 1
    return fib(i-1) + fib(i-2)

@memo
def fib_memo(i):
    if i < 2: return 1
    return fib_memo(i-1) + fib_memo(i-2)
```

And now test the speed difference!

```
>>> print fib(200)
...
>>> print fib_memo(200)
...
```

Comment: This is the exact example I mention in the link in the question. The usefulness of decorators in this scenario prompted me to seek further use cases like this :)

Comment: @subiet I didn't read the article, classical example, it almost seems like an exact copy paste :). Anyways, when you work with algorithms, nodes and graphs memo is used to remove what is called recursive complexity (especially useful in partitioning and searches).